# How to split string in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to split string in two parts using space as a separator. I had tried the below code but i got wrong result.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char str_1[5], str_2[5], my_str[] = "hello world";

    //storing hello in str_1.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
        str_1[i] = my_str[i];
    puts(str_1);

    //storing world in str_2.
    for (int i = 6, j = 0; i <= 10; ++i, ++j)
        str_2[j] = my_str[i];
    puts(str_2);
}
```

Expected output:

```
hello
world
```

Getting output:

```
hello
worldhello
```

Comment: `str_1` and `str_2` are too short, and, you forgot to add string terminators.

Comment: Your strings are missing string terminators `'\0'`

Comment: Also what do you think `i <= 10, j <= 4` does in the condition of the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to terminate the string using `\0` using null character as last character of the string. Try the below code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char str_1[6], str_2[6], my_str[] = "hello world";

    //storing hello in str_1.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
        str_1[i] = my_str[i];

    str_1[5] = '\0';
    puts(str_1);

    //storing world in str_2.
    for (int i = 6, j = 0; i <= 10; ++i, ++j)
        str_2[j] = my_str[i];

    str_2[5] = '\0';
    puts(str_2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_1` and `str_2` are arrays of char and the way you fill in the data is fine. But when you are using `puts()` method, you have to mark the end of the string by `'\0'` character as described in this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/

> The function begins copying from the address specified (str) until it
>   reaches the terminating null character ('\0'). This terminating
>   null-character is not copied to the stream.

Thus you have to add one more place in the `str_1` and `str_2` for the null-terminating character:

```
char str_1[6], str_2[6], my_str[] = "hello world";
```

Then after copying the substrings into those arrays, put '\0' right after the last copied character like this:

```
//storing hello in str_1.
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
    str_1[i] = my_str[i];
}

str_1[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple example, eg using [strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm):

First make sure variables contain enough space for the task:

```
 //char str_1[5], str_2[5], my_str[] = "hello world";//need minimum of 6 for each 5 char word
 //           ^         ^
 char str_1[6], str_2[6], my_str[] = "hello world";
 //         ^         ^      
 char *tok = strtok(my_str, " ");
 if(tok)
 {
     strcpy(str_1, tok);
     tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
     if(tok)
     {
         strcpy(str_2, tok);//Note - strcpy terminates target with NULL.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some basic mistakes in the code.Please go through c staring related theories.
please go through code and comments.

- staring should be always end with '\0' (null character).
- character array size should always +1 of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    /* array side should be (staring size + 1) here 1 is for staring terminator ('\0') */
    char str_1[6], str_2[6], my_str[] = "hello world";
    int i =0, j =0;
    //storing hello in str_1.
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
        str_1[i] = my_str[i];
    /* You need to add null terminator ('\0') at the end of the staring so that we can print it properly */
    str_1[i] = '\0';
    puts(str_1);

    //storing world in str_2.
    for (i = 6, j = 0; i <= 10; ++i, ++j)
        str_2[j] = my_str[i];
    /* You need to add null terminator ('\0') at the end of the staring so that we can print it properly */
    str_2[j] = '\0';
    puts(str_2);
}
```